# Jboss migration from jboss 6.0 to jboss 7.1

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

I am migrating JBoss 6 to jboss 7.1 and I get to know that jboss 7.1 follows moduler approach and loads only some specific jars like activation.jar, jboss-ejb-api.jar ,transaction.jar etc and for other jars we give entry in jboss-deployement-structure.xml file.
  can anybody please help me know how does it loads implicit jars.where the entry of these implicit jars is provided(any xml file etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Other libraries (i.e. modules) you want your application to have access to is provided from the jboss-deployment-structure.xml. Libraries packaged in your application etc are loaded in the applications classloader I believe.

Answer (score 0):

There is no XML, this is specified in Java-code (deployment processors). There is documentation when modules are added implicitly in: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Implicit+module+dependencies+for+deployments